What should I pass in retriever parameter in ConversationalRetrievalChain function to create a conversational bot
I am creating a chatbot which generates oracle query based upon the user question. I have provided the table structures and other DB related things in the SystemMessage and user question in HumanMessage. It was working fine and queries were getting created.
Now, I want it to be a conversational bot so that it can be interactive and can generate/modify the responses based upon user requirement.
Since it doesn't require any document for embedding and vector store what should I pass in retriever parameter.
My code:
import logging
import json
import langchain
import os

from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

from langchain.chains.conversational_retrieval.base import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain.prompts import SystemMessagePromptTemplate, HumanMessagePromptTemplate, ChatPromptTemplate,MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain_openai import AzureChatOpenAI
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory

from src.dao.dbConnect import getFromDb

langchain.verbose = False
langchain.debug = False
langchain.llm_cache = False

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger("uvicorn")

def getResponseFromModel(guide, question, environment):
    
    chat_history = []
    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)
    
    messages = [
    SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(guide),
    MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="chat_history"),
    HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(question)
]

    client_id = os.environ["CLIENT_ID"]
    client_key =os.environ["CLIENT_KEY"]
    credential = ClientSecretCredential(
        client_id=client_id,
        client_secret=client_key,
        tenant_id=os.environ["TENANT_ID"]
    )

    token = credential.get_token("https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/.default")

    model = AzureChatOpenAI(
        azure_endpoint=os.environ["AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT"],
        openai_api_version=os.environ["AZURE_OPENAI_API_VERSION"],
        azure_deployment=os.environ["AZURE_OPENAI_CHAT_DEPLOYMENT_NAME"],
        openai_api_key=token.token,
        temperature=0,
        top_p = 0.1
    )

    
    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(messages=messages)

    logger.info("Fetching Response from model")

    qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm= model, 
    retriever= , #Here I am getting the issue
    memory=memory,
    combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": prompt}
)
    
    response = qa({"question": question, "chat_history": chat_history})

    #response = model.invoke(message)
    response_content = json.loads(response["answer"].strip('```json').strip('```').strip())
    result = ""
    if response_content['question_type'] == 'sql':
        df = getFromDb(
            str(response_content['response']).replace("sql", "").replace("`", ""), environment
        )
        result = json.dumps({"query": (response_content['response']).replace("sql", "").replace("`", ""), "result": df})
    else:
        result = json.dumps({"result": (response_content['response']).replace("sql", "").replace("`", "")})
    return result


Well ConversationalRetrievalChain is used to be provided with a query and to answer it using documents retrieved from the query.

since you're not using document retrieval, You can use None
qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm=model,
    retriever=None,  # Set to None since no document retrieval is needed
    memory=memory,
    combine_docs_chain_kwargs={"prompt": prompt}
)

